# Export gridview to excel with all formatting of gidview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to export gidview to excel with all gridview's formatting applied. I do not have any controls inside my gridview, all style applied.
is there any options available?

Comment: May I ask what have you tried yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your best and easiest bet: http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview

```
var bindingSource = (BindingSource)this.peopleDataGridView.DataSource;
var dataTable = ((DataView)bindingSource.List).Table;
var ef = new ExcelFile();
var ws = ef.Worksheets.Add(dataTable.TableName);
// Insert data table in worksheet, starting from worksheet's first row and column and    include column headers
ws.InsertDataTable(dataTable, 0, 0, true);

foreach(ExcelCell cell in ws.GetUsedCellRange(true))
   cell.Style.FillPattern.SetSolid(Color.Red);
ef.SaveXls(dataTable.TableName + ".xls");
```

Another option is to use http://www.completit.com/Portfolio/DGVE/Screenshots.aspx

[Added 1 more ]
This one converts DGV to XML/XSL which is the best, if you want to manipulate data in HTML or other format along with EXCEL.
http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/ExcelXmlWriter/

All of above  are free and export formatting from DGV to EXCEL.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes the free version has limitation!! I just checked http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/free-version and the free version has max 15o rows and 5 sheets limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your requirements but you can try this control:

[ExportToExcel](http://exporttoexcel.codeplex.com/)

There is a property called ApplyStyleInExcel you need to set to true.